# How do I get g++/gcc 4.6 on my Ubuntu 11.04 (Natty Narwhal)?

Tags: c++, gcc, ubuntu, g++

I've been googling for the last half an hour and can't seem to find the answer to this - I want g++/gcc 4.6 for my Ubuntu install so I can get all the new cool C++0x features. I tried installing the g++-4.6_4.6.1-9ubuntu3_386.deb package but I get an error in the software center. (Dependency is not satisfiable: gcc-4.6-base)

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks!

Comment: You need the other packages, like `gcc-4.6-base`. And you could upgrade your system (to Ubuntu 12), or compile GCC 4.6 from source.

Comment: If I enter gcc-4.6 into synaptic package manager nothing comes up :S

Comment: Not quite sure why this received a -1 seen as I stated clearly that I'd spent time researching why this didn't seem to work and how to get it working...

Comment: Belongs on askubuntu.com, obviously; unfortunately the close menu does not allow migrating there.

Comment: Why do you need it on Natty? It's not a LTS and it's almost a year old, so you should have updated long ago. Yes, it is still supported, but if you want latest goodness, you should just update.

Comment: Because thats the version of Ubuntu im running on?

Comment: So if I upgrade to 11.10 I'll get g++ 4.6?

Comment: @Jarob22: LTS = Long Term Support. You didn't even know, so you obviously don't need it. Which means you should update to 11.10 (Oneiric) and to update to 12.04 (Precise) when it comes out. That's the easiest way to get new goodness.

Comment: @Jarob22: Yes, Oneiric has gcc 4.6. See http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gcc&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

Comment: Meh ok, I was trying to avoid upgrading because..meh :P alright then, I'll do that then hopefully get g++ 4.6 goodness :3 thanks! Edit: post this as an answer and I'll set it as selected answer for this q :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Natty Narwhal is almost a year old. There is already 11.10 Oneiric Ocelot and that [has gcc 4.6.1](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gcc&searchon=names&suite=oneiric&section=all). Upgrading the system to Oneiric is the easiest way. It's as easy as switching the suite in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and starting synaptic or aptitude and running update+upgrade.

Answer (score 3):

You can build a gcc/g++ 4.6 tool chain from scratch. I remember there is a tool can do this for you, it need you specify the gcc and glib version, and it will download/build whole tool chain for you, but I can't remember the tool's name now. Any way, you can start from [Installing GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/index.html) ;O)

Comment: That's a very, very bad starting point. Rebuilding packages from newer release is much easier and much better, because you still get the package management goodness.

Comment: @JanHudec Some time you don't have the luck to get a "package management goodness", especially for cross-compile environment, so if you had worked in a multi-toolchain project, you will don't think it as bad as you think ;o)

Comment: A cross-compile environment is something entirely different. But if you have a system where you can get the correct compiler by simply upgrading that system, building your own is not the right way to go.